# jQuery UI Datepicker altField .change function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

Can anyone tell me why the `console.log` line isn't getting run when I select a date with the jQuery UI Datepicker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ altField: '#dateIntermediate'});
        });
        $('#dateIntermediate').change(function(){ 
            console.log("dateIntermediate changed");
        });
    });
</script>
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<input type="hidden" id="dateIntermediate" />
```

Comment: I think since it is a hidden field, it is not triggered. DOM onchange event is defined only for the following elements: <input type="text">, <select>, <textarea> (from w3schools.com). Try changing it to text box for testing.

Answer (score 7):

The browser just doesn't fire the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) in these cases (setting the value by script), if you want to know when it happens though, you can use the [`onSelect` handler](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) for the datepicker, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    altField: '#dateIntermediate',
    onSelect: function() { 
      alert('Current #dateIntermediate value: ' + $("#dateIntermediate").val());
    }
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WaFSh/1/).  Or, alternatively you can trigger the `change` handler you currently have in the same way:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    altField: '#dateIntermediate',
    onSelect: function() { 
      $("#dateIntermediate").change();
    }
  });
  $('#dateIntermediate').change(function(){ 
    console.log("dateIntermediate changed");
  });
});​
```

[You can test that here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WaFSh/2/)

---

As an aside, you don't need the `$(window).ready(function() { });` wrapper on there, it's equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { });` which is already handled by your `$(function() { });` wrapper.  Your current method works because `$(anything).ready()` all goes to the same place, but there's no need for more than one wrapper, so just remove the outer one :)

Comment: This approach works okay, except when you have selected a date using keyboard navigation, then tab away from the datepicker field. In this case, the altField does retain the date you just chose, but the `change` event is not fired on the the altField. Any ideas anyone?